# Leetcode 219 Runtime Error with javascript

Tags: javascript

**Problem Description:**

Given an array of integers and an integer `k`, find out whether there are two distinct indices `i` and `j` in the array such that `nums[i] = nums[j]` and the absolute difference between `i` and `j` is at most `k`.

```
var containsDuplicate = function(nums, k) {
   var maps = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      var key = nums[i];
      if (maps[key] == undefined) {
         maps[key] = i;
      } else if (i - maps[key] < k) {
         return true;
      } else {
         maps[key] = i;
      }
   }
   return false;
}
```

Anyone who can tell me the reason.

Comment: please put the aray nums, to saw it better, because your code in some lines makes me confuses

Comment: Your method name "containsDuplicate" indicates another problem than the one you mention in your description: aka checking the absolute difference. Please clarify the problem and formulate a question that you need an answer for.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to determine if a number ahead by `k` equals the current number `n`, which will return true and stop iterating immediately.

```js
function containsDuplicate(nums, k) {
  return nums.some((n, i) => n === nums[i + k]);
}

console.log('--- Testing for true ---');
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,8,5,3,9,5], 2));
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,8,6,3,9,5], 5));
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,5,6,3,9,6], 1));
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,8,6,5,9,6], 3));

console.log('--- Testing for false ---');
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,8,6,3,9,5], 2));
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,8], 2));
console.log(containsDuplicate([5,5], 2));
console.log(containsDuplicate([], 2));
```